# Yii2 handle beforesave event in behaviour

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app

i try to develop application with yii2 framework,i use beforeSave event to handle createdAt and updatedAt with time() function, this method is :

```
public function beforeSave($insert)
{
    if ($insert) {
        $this->createdAt = time();
    }

    $this->updatedAt = time();

    return parent::beforeSave($insert);
}
```

i just wanna move this method to behaviour and attach it to my model, i create the behaviour class and attach the behaviour to model but it does not work abd pass null to database, my behaviour class is :

```
namespace app\modules\imdb\behaviors;

use yii\base\Behavior;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;

class saveTimeBehavior extends Behavior
{

   public function events()
   {
       return [
           ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT => 'beforeSave',
       ];
   }


   public function beforeSave($event)
   {
       if ($event) {
          $this->createdAt = time();
       }

       $this->updatedAt = time();

       return parent::beforeSave($event);
   }
}
```

and the attach code in my model is :

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        saveTimeBehavior::className(),
    ];
}
```

please help me to handle this with correct way, thanks alot :)

Comment: why are'nt you using `TimeStampBehavior` ? why making your own

Comment: do select the answer if it worked out for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [**`TimeStampBehavior`**](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-behaviors-timestampbehavior.html). If you have declared the columns(`created_at, updated_at`) as `int(11)` for being `UNIX timestamp`.

```
use yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior;

public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        TimestampBehavior::className(),
    ];
}
```

But as your attribute names are different or you want to use a different way of calculating the timestamp, you may configure the [**`$createdAtAttribute`**](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-behaviors-timestampbehavior.html#$createdAtAttribute-detail), [**`$updatedAtAttribute`**](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-behaviors-timestampbehavior.html#$updatedAtAttribute-detail) and [**`$value`**](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-behaviors-timestampbehavior.html#$value-detail) properties like the following:

```
use yii\db\Expression;
use yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior;

public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        [
            'class' => TimestampBehavior::className(),
            'createdAtAttribute' => 'createdAt',
            'updatedAtAttribute' => 'updatedAt',
            'value' => new Expression('NOW()'),
        ],
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Uou can do that in a simple way , by identify the type of `created_at` and `updated_at` as `timestamp` when you create the table, and it will be automatically filled in the database when you add new record or update existing one.

Example :

```
     'created_at'=> $this->timestamp(),
     'updated_at'=> $this->timestamp(),
```

**Note:** You can find more information about creating table using the below link : [Yii2 Migration](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-migrations.html)

Comment: tanx for your answer, but my task is handle this with behaviour, can you help me ?

Comment: you can use timestamp behavior to do that inside the **behavior* function , like this :

Comment: 'public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            [
                'class' => TimestampBehavior::className(),
                'attributes'=>[
                    BaseActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT => 'createdAt',
                    BaseActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_UPDATE => 'updatedAt',
                ],
                'value'=>function(){return date('Y-m-d H:i:s');}
            ]
        ];
    }'

Comment: you can go the below link to know more information : [TimestampBehavior](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-behaviors-timestampbehavior.html)

Comment: added an answer see if it helps